# run tkinter gui app on startup without desktop

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I was looking for an answer but could not find anything related.

I would like like to build self-ordering kiosk with touchscreen based on Linux Ubuntu. The system should start automatically with single tkinter gui app, but I don't need any desktop.

Also If the app crash for any reason I don't want anyone to see any desktop - the black screen would be perfect.

I was looking into openbox - would that work?
Can you please guide me into which direction I should look into?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application

I have done similar things in Debian though.

Comment: Hi @Meritor, can you tell me which mentioned method you used? Thanks

Comment: let me post that as an answer... too long for a comment

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not actually answering the question as the flavour of the operating system is different here.

This was done on Debian with LXDE desktop. I wrote an automated setup script for my software, copying some snippet from that here.

Note sure if you have the same scenario.

###### Step 1 Disable the LXDE desktop:

I had commented out lxpanel and xscreensaver both from the default autostart and user autostart

```
  #DISABLE THE DESKTOP
  sudo sed -i 's/^@lxpanel/#@lxpanel/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
  sudo sed -i 's/^@xscreensaver/#@xscreensaver/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
  #DISABLE THE DESKTOP FOR THE USER
  sudo sed -i 's/^@lxpanel/#@lxpanel/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-${user_name}/autostart
  sudo sed -i 's/^@xscreensaver/#@xscreensaver/g' /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-${user_name}/autostart
```

###### Step 2 Setup the application:

> Note: I was using python3.7

```
#SETUP PYTHON VENV
python3 -m venv ${application_root_dir}/venv
cd ${application_root_dir}/venv
source ${application_root_dir}/venv/bin/activate

# Install external dependencies, if any
pip3 install <dependecny_name>

# Install your software
pip3 install <software>
deactivate
```

###### Step 3 Prepare for Atuostart (optional):

Create Script to be executed in autostart. Note this is optional, you can directly use your command in the auto start (step 4).

```
tee -a ${application_root_dir}/start_my_app.sh > /dev/null << EOT
#!/bin/bash
cd ${application_root_dir}
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m package.MyApp
deactivate
EOT

# Set execute permissions
sudo chmod 744 ${root_dir}/start_my_app.sh
```

###### Step 4 Steup Atuostart:

> Note: you can execute any command by setting `ExecStart` in `[service]`

###### 4.1 Create a new service

```
# CREATE A SERVICE FILE
sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/my_app.service > /dev/null << EOT
[Unit]
Description=Start MY_APPLICATION
After=default.target
Wants=default.target

[Service]
User=${user_name}
Group=$user_group
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTORITY=/home/${user_name}/.Xauthority
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "${root_dir}/start_my_app.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOT
```

###### 4.2 Register and enable the service

```
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl enable my_app.service
```

###### 4.3 Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

> Note: To enable the desktop back for troubleshooting (if at all required - I never needed though, as ssh was enabled in my case so I was using terminal). Uncomment the commented part of lxde deskop and reboot.

Comment: Thanks !!!, I will give it a try

Comment: keep it posted on how it goes.. feel free to ask if you are stuck